# Scroll to section with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i made a navigation bar which i want to scroll to a specific section when clicked.
Here is a fragment of the html code for my navigation and four sections, with the Javascript code(jquery).***The problem is that it always scrolls to the top of my site and not to the specific sections.*** All sections have a declared height and position set to relative.

```
<nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#" class="start">
                <li>Start</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="about">
                <li>About</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="products">
                <li>Products</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="contact">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<header class="welcome" data-section="start">
<main class="about" data-section="about">
<section class="products" data-section="products">
<div class="kontakt" data-section="contact">

<script>
$('nav ul a').on('click',function(){
    const goToSection = "[data-section=" + $(this).attr('class') + "]";
    $('html body').animate({scrollTop: $(goToSection).offset.top})
})<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Its `.offset().top` not `.offset.top`
- It will be much easier and better to add data-class attribute to the anchor so you can use `$(this).data('class').trim()` instead of `$(this).attr('class')` <sup>(`trim()` to avoid any white-spaces)</sup>
- Comma needed in `$('html body')` to be `$('html, body')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav ul a').on('click',function(){
      const goToSection = "[data-section=" + $(this).data('class').trim() + "]";
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(goToSection).offset().top})
  });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  position : fixed;
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
.menu a{
  color : #fff;
}
header , main , section{
  background : yellow;
  height : 500px;
  margin : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#" class="start" data-class="start">
                <li>Start</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="about" data-class="about">
                <li>About</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="products" data-class="products">
                <li>Products</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="contact" data-class="contact">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<header class="welcome" data-section="start">Welcome</header>
<main class="about" data-section="about">About</main>
<section class="products" data-section="products">Products</section>
<div class="kontakt" data-section="contact">Contact</div>
```

Comment: Your're totally welcome @Frontmaniaac .. Have a great day :-)